# EncryptionProvider in Office add-in ( VSTO or COM )

Tags: encryption, ms-word, vsto, office-addins, word-addins

I'm having a problem of finding the right way to use **EncryptionProvider** property of **Word.Document** class in VSTO add-in for Word.

Every time I try to set any value (Add-in 'ProgId', other encryption providers, random strings) to it I receive **OutOfMemoryException**.
I tried implementing **Office.EncryptionProvider** interface in addIn class and in separate class and non of it's methods gets executed at all. After I set any value to EncryptionProvider VSTO executes **RequestService** override of my add-in object asking for Office.EncryptionProvider GUID object, but whatever I return there it does nothing (at least no exceptions or anything visible).

Problem worsens as MSDN or any other documentation I have found had minimal description ( and obvious based on method/class names) and no examples.

So what is the correct way of using EncryptionProvider in Office add-in?

Comment: What is your current implementation of the provider? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

In your VSTO add-in you need to implement the [EncryptionProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.encryptionprovider?view=office-pia) interface. You must return an instance of this interface when a correspodning guid is requested in the `RequestService` overridden function.

Then try to do the following steps:

1. Open the windows registry editor (regedit.exe).
2. Look for the following registry subkey:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Common
   ```
3. Create a new `Key` there.
4. Type `Security`, and then press ENTER.
5. Locate the following registry subkey:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\XX.0\Common\Security
   ```
6. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click String value.
7. Type `DeprecatedProviders`, and then press ENTER.
8. In the Details pane, right-click DeprecatedProviders, and then click Modify.
9. In the Value data box, type The Custom CSP Name, and then click OK.
10. Exit Registry Editor.

Where the XX.0 is the Office version installed on your machine. I suppose that now your add-in should work correctly with Word.

See [Custom Encryption in VSTO](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e90f5422-e105-4aa0-8dae-461aa17e326e/custom-encryption-in-vsto?forum=vsto) for more information.